# How can I get Microsoft Word 2003 to go left-to-right by default

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003, right-to-left

Whenever I open MSWord 2003, the direction is right-to-left. It becomes very annoying to reset paragraphs back to left-to-right every time. How can I fix this?

I tried deleting `C:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dot`, to no avail.

Is there a configuration setting?

I have Windows XP with English as the primary language but Hebrew enabled as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the input language in the control panel -> Time, Language, and Regional Options.

Here is an article [on how to do so](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/enable-right-to-left-language-support-for-word-HA001130617.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That did it: Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Office, point to Microsoft Office Tools, and then click Microsoft Office 2003 Language Settings.

Comment: No probs.  Glad it worked for you.